# busboy wait for field data before accepting file upload

Tags: node.js

Is something like this even possible, or are there better ways to do this? Is what Im doing even a good idea, or is this a bad approach?

What I want to do is upload a file to my nodejs server. Along with the file I want to send some meta data. The meta data will determine if the file can be saved and the upload accepted, or if it should be rejected and sending a 403 response.

I am using busboy and I am sending FormData from my client side.

The example below is very much simplified:

Here is a snippet of the client side code.
I am appending the file as well as the meta data to the form

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('name', JSON.stringify({name: "John Doe"}));
formData.append('file', this.selectedFile, this.selectedFile.name);
```

Here is the nodejs side:

```
exports.Upload = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        var acceptUpload = false;
        const bb = busboy({ headers: req.headers });

        bb.on('field', (fieldname, val) => {
            //Verify data here before accepting file upload
            var data = JSON.parse(val);
            if (val.name === 'John Doe') {
                acceptUpload = true;
            } else {
                acceptUpload = false;
            }
        });

        bb.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
            if (acceptUpload) {
                const saveTo = '/upload/file.txt'
                file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
            }else{
                response = {
                    message: 'Not Authorized'
                }
                res.status(403).json(response);
            }
        });
        bb.on('finish', () => {
            response = {
                message: 'Upload Successful'
            }
            res.status(200).json(response);
        });
        req.pipe(bb);

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        response = {
            message: error.message
        }
        res.status(500).json(response);
    }
}
```

So basically, is it even possible for the 'field' event-handler to wait for the 'file' event handler? How could one verify some meta data before accepting a file upload?

How can I do validation of all data in the form data object, before accepting the file upload? Is this even possible, or are there other ways of uploading files with this kind of behaviour? I am considering even adding data to the request header, but this does not seem like the ideal solution.

**Update**

As I suspected, nothing is waiting. Which ever way I try, the upload first has to be completed, only then after is it rejected with a 403

**Another Update**

Ive tried the same thing with multer and have similar results. Even when I can do the validation, the file is completely uploaded from the client side. Once the upload is complete, only then the request is rejected. The file, however, never gets stored, even though it is uploaded in its entirety.

Comment: What is the problem with the current implementation?

Comment: Well, so far it does not appear to be waiting and just continues uploading and only after uploading the request is rejected

Comment: After uploading the file only a call will come to this function, I don't think you can handle it before uploading the file.

In multer you can handle this, If the body has some parameters you can reject them before injecting middleware.

Comment: Oky, I implemented the same thing with multer. For some reason I cant do the validation before accepting the file upload. Even if the validation fails,  the file is completely uploaded and then the request is rejected and the file deleted. I could not find a way around this yet. Im guessing this is just the way it works and no workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `busboy`, nothing is written to the server if you do not execute the statement `file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));`

You can prevent more data from even being uploaded to the server by executing the statement `req.destroy()` in the `.on("field", ...)` or the `.on("file", ...)` event handler, even after you have already evaluated some of the fields. Note however, that `req.destroy()` destroys not only the current HTTP request but the entire TCP connection, which might otherwise have been reused for subsequent HTTP requests. (This applies to HTTP/1.1, in HTTP/2 the relationship between connections and requests is different.)

At any rate, it has no effect on the current HTTP request if everything has already been uploaded. Therefore, whether this saves any network traffic depends on the size of the file. And if the decision whether to `req.destroy()` involves an asynchronous operation, such as a database lookup, then it may also come too late.

Compare

```bash
> curl -v -F name=XXX -F file=@<small file> http://your.server
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Empty reply from server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

with

```bash
> curl -v -F name=XXX -F file=@<large file> http://your.server
> Expect: 100-continue
< HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* Send failure: Connection was reset
* Closing connection 0
curl: (55) Send failure: Connection was reset
```

Note that the client sets the `Expect` header before uploading a large file. You can use that fact in connection with a special request header `name` in order to block the upload completely:

```
http.createServer(app)
.on("checkContinue", function(req, res) {
  if (req.headers["name"] === "John Doe") {
    res.writeContinue(); // sends HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
    app(req, res);
  } else {
    res.statusCode = 403;
    res.end("Not authorized");
  }
})
.listen(...);
```

But for small files, which are uploaded without the `Expect` request header, you still need to check the `name` header in the `app` itself.

Comment: Thanks. so much! This really helped to understand the problem better. So essentially, then only real way to prevent any data from being uploaded, is to add everything required to validate the request in the header. Ill implement it in that way then