# file.size undefined in Multer

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I'm using multer to handle a multi-file upload, and the middleware "filename", like this:

```
  filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(Object.keys(file));
    ({ rows } = await db.query(`
    INSERT INTO public.files(
      uuid,
      nom,
      type,
      size
    )
    VALUES
    ($1, $2, $3, $4)
    RETURNING *`, [
      req.uuid,
      file.originalname,
      file.mimetype,
      file.size,
      // +req.headers["content-length"],
    ]));
    cb(null, uuid);
  },
```

The problem is that `file.size` remains undefined. I control that the size exists before sending the files to the API. When I check which properties are available (see the `console.log`), I only have `'fieldname', 'originalname', 'encoding', 'mimetype'`.

If I use `+req.headers["content-length"]` it takes into account the size of all the request (all the files), and not only the current file.

Why can't I have the file size? Is it impossible or should I edit some setting I haven't found in the documentation?

Comment: But why are you making query to database in multer's `filename` function ? it will just make things worse.  you can access file(s) in `req` object passed in handler's argument.

Comment: I generate a fake file name (uuid) for every file, so that on the server there is no way to search files by the name. But I have to keep the track of the link "real name/uuid". That's why when a filename is proceeded, I insert a new line in the database.

Comment: size is assigned after the file is processed/saved. it's still unclear why it has to be done in `filename` method, and not in route handler/middleware..

Comment: The content type [`multipart/form-data`](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7578#section-4.8) does not support a `Content-Length` header field in the individual parts (only for the overall request). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75373619/busboy-wait-for-field-data-before-accepting-file-upload for how to get more control over the upload process. Do you want to know the file size in order to restrict network traffic, or to restrict the load on your server?

Comment: @traynor: I'll have to find a way to get each separate file after the multer middleware, then. For the moment I haven't found a solution.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen: it's to keep track of the size of the files in the database and detect doubles or detect which users are likely to upload large files.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 use [.array()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#arrayfieldname-maxcount), and then in the route handler loop `req.files` and save stuff to database. you can also limit file size.  but if you're trying to prevent file from being saved in case it's a duplicate etc., well, that's a different case, but that's not visible from your OP..

Comment: @traynor:  yes, I didn't want to pollute the  question. I'll do what you're suggesting, my only fear is that the files don't come in the same order during the "filename" middleware and the route handler. For the moment it does but I don't know if it's consistent and the file are always processed in the same order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @traynor, here is what I did:

I added a middleware after the upload:

```
router.post('/',
  upload.array('files'),
  handleFiles,
  ...
```

I simplified my upload:

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: async (req, file, cb) => {
    let folder = config.get('api.files');
    req.uuid = uuid.v4();    
    folder += `/${req.uuid.charAt(0)}/${req.uuid.charAt(1)}/`;
    await fsPromises.mkdir(folder, { recursive: true });
    cb(null, folder);
  },
  filename: async (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, req.uuid);
  },
});

const upload = multer({ storage });
```

And I handled the logic with the new middleware:

```
const handleFiles = async (req, res, next) => {
  // my logic here, with req.files having f.size for each file
  // and f.originalname anf f.filename

  next();
}
```